# Use php callable to call constructor

Tags: php, callable

I am trying to call a class' constructor through a callable, so I had the following code:

```
$callable = array('Foo', '__construct');
```

However calling this will throw the following error:

```
Fatal error: Non-static method Foo::__construct() cannot be called statically
```

I understand that the constructor is not a static method, but I can't use an existing instance to call the constructor for a new instance (as it will just call the constructor on the existing object again), is there any way at all to call a constructor like this?

Comment: Can you please provide more code on your problem?

Comment: Yes, `new className;` or `new classname($params);`.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, sounds like you need `new`

Comment: I am aware that I can use new, but I am specifically looking to create a new instance through call_user_func

Comment: "I am aware that I can use new, but I am specifically looking to create a new instance through call_user_func" => Any reason why?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php

Comment: There was no real reason, aside from my own curiosity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have to use `call_user_func`, this might work, though it's not clear why you would want to do this:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass("Foo");
$instance = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
call_user_func(array($instance, '__construct'));
```

Comment: Argh, just 1 minute before I wanted to post a [ReflectionClass::newInstance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php) answer.

Comment: The same class also has the two very handy methods `newInstance` and `newInstanceArgs` which call the constructor with arguments. `newInstance` takes a variable argument list, while `newInstanceArgs` takes all arguments as array.

Comment: It should be noted that repeatedly calling `call_user_func([$instance, '__construct'])` with this solution does not create new instances. Instead, it repeatedly calls `__construct()` on the same instance. If you want to create new instances with call_user_func(), you need one of the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a simple way to dynamically choose which class to construct, you can use a variable name with the `new` keyword, like so:

```
$inst = new $class_name;
// or, if the constructor takes arguments, provide those in the normal way:
$inst = new $class_name('foo', 'bar');
```

However, if what you need is a way of passing the constructor to something which is already expecting a callable, the best I can think of is to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$callable = function() { return new Foo; }
call_user_func( $callable );
```

Or using the short single-expression closure syntax introduced in PHP 7.4:

```
$callable = fn() => new Foo;
call_user_func( $callable );
```

Answer (score 1):

The more correct answer, as @MauganRa already mentioned in a comment, is using `\ReflectionClass::newInstance()` or `\ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs()`. I think this should be expressed in a full answer.

Now if you want to pass this around as a callback and use `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()`, try this:

```
$callable = [new \ReflectionClass('C'), 'newInstance'];
```

Or a more fleshed-out example:

```
class Car {
  private $color;
  private $size;

  public function __construct($color, $size) {
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->size = $size;
  }

  public function describe() {
      return "A $this->size $this->color car.";
  }
}

$callable = [new \ReflectionClass('Car'), 'newInstance'];

$cars = [];
$cars[] = call_user_func($callable, 'red', 'big')->describe();
$cars[] = call_user_func_array($callable, ['blue', 'small'])->describe();

var_export($cars);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/7fvQL

I am not aware of another / better solution.